# docker compose ignoring env vars when creating the container for postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

I always get role x does not exist which means the db was created with the default username and my env vars was ignored, any idea whats going on here?

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  PostgreSQL:
    container_name: db-name
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PG_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${PG_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${PG_DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

When I look in kitematic I see the correct env variables and values, but nothing is taking in consideration by the db

Comment: Are you sure the database was not already created? It will only be created and initialized if the files in /var/lib/postgresql/data from your mounted volume are empty.

Comment: I up with forece recreate docker-compose up --force-recreate I don't think the db will persist

Comment: I tried docker-compose down --remove-orphans --volumes still same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing docker-compose down to remove the container and do again docker-compose up, you can get more help from this [link](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/203#issuecomment-254056476)

Comment: thank you for the link I found an answer there, I had the manually delete the ./postgres-data created by docker compose